# Java Simple Phonebook

Tags: java, array

This Program is a simple phonebook, user is given 3 choice, add a number to the phone book, dial a number or exit the program. Are there Any Improvements that i can make, either efficient or cleaning the code or something useful i can add?

````
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneBookV2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        print(numbers);
        task(numbers);
    }

    public static void task(ArrayList<String> numbers){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Pick A Task: \n 1:Add A Number to Speed Dial \n 2:Speed Dial A Number \n 3:Exit");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();

        switch(choice){
            case "1":

                AddNumber(numbers);
                break;
            case "2":
                CallNumber(numbers);
                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void CallNumber(ArrayList<String> numbers) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            String[][] keys = {
                    {" ", "1", " ", "2", " ", "3"},
                    {" ", "4", " ", "5", " ", "6"},
                    {" ", "7", " ", "8", " ", "9"},
                    {" ", " ", " ", "0", " ", " "}
            };
            printPhoneBook(keys);

            System.out.println("Pick A Speed Dial Number");
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            String phoneNum = "";

            switch (choice) {
                case 1 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(0);
                case 2 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(1);
                case 3 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(2);
                case 4 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(3);
                case 5 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(4);
                case 6 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(5);
                case 7 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(6);
                case 8 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(7);
                case 9 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(8);
                case 0 -> phoneNum = numbers.get(9);
                default -> System.out.println("No Number Saved At " + choice);


            }
            if (phoneNum != null) System.out.println("Dialing " + phoneNum + "....");
            else System.out.println("There is No Number At This Location");
            PhoneBookV2.task(numbers);
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("There is No Number At This Location");
            PhoneBookV2.task(numbers);
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> AddNumber(ArrayList<String> numbers) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean cont = false;

        do {
            System.out.print("Please Enter The Number You Wish To Save Under Speed Dial: ");

            // Add the next number to the ArrayList
            numbers.add(scanner.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Would you like to add another? Yes or No: ");
            String answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (answer.equals("yes")) continue;
            if (answer.equals("no")) {
                print(numbers);
                cont = true;
            }

        } while (!cont);
        PhoneBookV2.task(numbers);
        return numbers;
    }

    public static void printPhoneBook(String[][] keys){

        for(String[] row : keys){
            for(String s : row){
                System.out.print(s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void print(ArrayList<String> numbers){
        for(int i = 0; i< numbers.size(); i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ") " + numbers.get(i));
        }

    }


}
```
````

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

These are my suggestions:

1. No need to invoke `print` before `task` in main. At that point, the numbers would be empty anyway.
2. Better to declare numbers as : `List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();` (interface name on the left side) and make all parameters as `List<String> numbers` instead of `ArrayList<String> numbers`. This would minimize the code changes if you plan to use a different implementation of `List` instead of `ArrayList` in future.
3. You are currently not closing the `Scanner` objects. It would be good to use try with resources : `try(Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) { //code}`
4. Better to follow naming conventions : method names follow camel-case convention.
5. In `CallNumber` instead of the big `switch-case`, simple `if-else` is required. (Also it would be nice if speed dial 1 is `numbers.get(1)` instead of `numbers.get(0)`, so that you could just use `numbers.get(choice)`)

```java
String phoneNum = null; // should not be initialized as "", otherwise dialing message would be displayed even if choice is invalid.
if(choice >= 0 && choice <= 9) {
    phoneNum = numbers.get((choice + 9) % 10);
} else {
    // error message
}
```

6. I believe `cont` in `AddNumber` is used to indicate continue adding numbers. But the loop executes when this is `false`. So the naming and the actual use do not match. You could have initialized it to `true`, then use a `while(cont)` instead of `do-while(!cont)` and for choice `no` you could have set `cont = false`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know where to begin here.

- If you only allow 10 numbers, why bother with an arraylist, an array would do
- If you allow a choice of 0 - 9, why do you have to change the chosen values for indexing in such an ugly way? If you want to use 1-based numbering for the phone numbers, just do that by simple arithmetic
- You use far too many Scanners, none of which you close - you only need one
- You use recursion - calling the "choose a task" method at the end of each task method - for a process which is naturally iterative. You've written loops elsewhere, so why not for the main process?
- You have no object-orientation - this is procedural code, just written in Java
- You don't validate input phone numbers - the user could enter -1 or "my dog has fleas" and the program would accept them
- As Gautham mentions (he makes a number of good points), the use of "cont" seems unintuitive
- The "if...else" in callNumber is non-standard format

Some basic ideas

- Split your code between the data and the user interaction - have a PhoneBook class with simple operations, like add, delete, retrieve and use that from your user interaction code
- Your main flow should then be a simple loop that asks for a choice of task, performs that task, then loops round again